# Error scrapy no se reconoce

Tags: python, cmd, scrapy

Estoy intentando correr un spider según la biblioteca de "*scrapy*" y al ejecutar la orden.

`scrapy runspider my_spider.py -o data.csv -t csv --set CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT=10`

Me señaliza el siguiente error

> scrapy no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o
>   archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: Tienes que buscar donde esta instalado scrapy y colocarlo en las variables del entorno

Comment: Pero se supone que scrapy esta instalado como package dentro de python ya tengo python entre mis variable de entorno, o estoy en un error ?

Comment: Estas en un error, Esta instalado dentro de una de las carpetas de python, por lo que el path de python no ayuda en ese caso. Pruebalo, nada pierdes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de tener instalado Scrapy via `pip` debes tener el directorio `Scripts` de tu instalación de Python en el PATH, donde por defecto se debería encontrar el ejecutable:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Primero **comprueba la ruta donde tienes instalado Python**, si tienes varias versiones del intérprete deberás buscar aquella donde tienes Scrapy instalado, por ejemplo para el directorio por defecto de instalación en W10 de Python 3.6 como se ve en la imágen anterior sería:

> C:\Users\**TuUsuario**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36

Después añade la ruta a `/Scripts` al Path, para el ejemplo anterior sería:

> C:\Users\**TuUsuario**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez agregada la ruta al Path no te olvides de reiniciar la terminal o abrir una nueva instancia de CMD para que tenga efecto el cambio.

La otra opción es que te sitúes con la terminal en el directorio `/Scripts` y una vez situado en él lo lances como haces ahora, o bien llames al ejecutable pasando su ruta absoluta:

> $ C:\Users\TuUsuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\scrapy runspider...

En este caso no importa, pero múltiples comandos de `scraper` (como `crawl`)  requieren tener un proyecto corretamente configurado.